# New tr after 5 td in php and tcpdf

Tags: php, html, html-table, tcpdf

I have a little problem with getting a new `<tr>` after every 5 `<td>` when making a PDF using TCPDF:

```
$bricks = "";
$bricks .= '<table>';
$bricks .= '<tr>';

foreach($bricks_selected as $key => $value) {
    $num_check = substr($value, 4);

    if($num_check != "0") {                
        $bricks .= '<td width="90" height="80"><img src="/var/www/brickmixer/bricks/tavler/RT'.substr($value, 0, 3).'.jpg" width="80" height="55"><br><b>RT '. substr($value, 0, 3) .' - '. $num_check .'%</b></td>';       
    } 

}
```

I have tried with division etc. but it gives me some funny results.

The `$bricks_selected` variable are set in the top of the script:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if($key == "bricks-selected") {
        $bricks_selected = explode("&", $value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an incremental variable and check every 5 `td`'s:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($bricks_selected as $key => $value) {
    $num_check = substr($value, 4);
    if($num_check != "0") {                
        $bricks .= '<td width="90" height="80"><img src="/var/www/brickmixer/bricks/tavler/RT'.substr($value, 0, 3).'.jpg" width="80" height="55"><br><b>RT '. substr($value, 0, 3) .' - '. $num_check .'%</b></td>';       
    } 
    if($i%5 == 0){
         echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: This gives me: Notice: Undefined index: startcolumn in /var/www/brickmixer/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 2445 if the number of items is exactly 5. But that must be an error in tcpdf ?

Comment: I changed the PDF library to mpdf instead! Then your answer works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you try to make an increment variable like $i, and `if ($i%5==0) {/* you have to close </tr> and open new <tr>*/}` `else {/* you do other thing*/}`